# How to get google calendar attachments

Tags: rest, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to get the attachment associated with a google calendar event using REST api call? I googled alot but have not found anything. Are google Labs features not compatible with   HTTP GET requests?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to generate the ICS file?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429907/exporting-single-google-calendar-events-to-ics

Comment: No, i am not generating ics files. I am making a GET call to fetch data from google calendar in my Titanium alloy mobile app which i am developing for both ios and android.I get all event data but the attachment, not even a link to it. any help??

Answer (score 1):

Attachments are now available in the Google Calendar API. Here is the guide: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#attachments

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this feature is not yet supported because the attachment is still a Google lab project.
You can always make a feature request.

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2545